# While() Loop to create a border of asterisks around text?

Tags: c++

Okay, I'm new at programming and decided to jump into this book called Accelerated C++. I'm only on the second chapter and I tried following the exercise, which is to create a program that asks for your name and then output it with a frame around it and padding.

When I execute it, it doesn't seem to be moving onto the next row. I'm guessing it's to do with my while() loop but I'm too dumb to figure out what it is exactly

```
// ask for a person's name, and greet the person
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::string;

int main()
{
// fetch name
cout << "Please enter your first name: ";
string name;
cin >> name;

// message
const string greeting = "Hello, " + name + "!";
// padding
const int pad = 1;
//desired rows/columns
const int rows = pad * 2 + 3;
const string::size_type cols = greeting.size() + pad * 2 + 2;
// seperate output from input
cout << std::endl;
// invariants
int r = 0;
string::size_type c = 0;

while (r != rows) {
    while(c != cols) {
        if (r == 0 || r == rows -1 || c == 0 || c == cols -1) { // if in bordering column or row
            cout << "*";   //output *
        } else {
            if (r == pad + 1 && c == pad + 1) { //if on row for greeting
                cout << greeting; // write greeting
                c += greeting.size(); // adjust invariant
            } else {
                cout << " ";
            }
        }
        ++c;
    }
    ++r;
    cout << std::endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: As my teacher used to say, you don't go to the McD and order a burger and a burger and a burger and a burger and .... But you do print a * and a * and a * and a * ...

Comment: While loops is not so good in this situation, now you know why. Also now you know why it is always good to declare variables as close to first use as possible. Great exercise!

Answer (score 5):

Consider moving the column counter c to nearer where you use it, then as tuckermi says it will start at 0 for each row.

```
while (r != rows) {
    string::size_type c = 0;
    while(c != cols) {
```

Answer (score 4):

At the bottom of your outer loop you need to reset the variable c to zero, otherwise it keeps its old value and won't re-enter the inner loop.

A good way to accomplish this is to move the definition/initialization of the variable into the beginning of the outer loop. That way c will be reinitialized before you start the inner loop each time.

Comment: Technically correct, but let's teach correct scoping. Move the statement `string::size_type c = 0;` **inside** the row-loop, so directly after the `while (r != rows) {` statement.

Comment: Updated appropriately

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there.

You need to clear c each row, and you need to take one off the greetings.size() to make it format properly (accounting for the fact you will be incrementing it later in the loop)

```
// ask for a person's name, and greet the person
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::string;

int main()
{
// fetch name
cout << "Please enter your first name: ";
string name;
cin >> name;

// message
const string greeting = "Hello, " + name + "!";
// padding
const int pad = 1;
//desired rows/columns
const int rows = pad * 2 + 3;
const string::size_type cols = greeting.size() + pad * 2 + 2;
// seperate output from input
cout << std::endl;
// invariants
int r = 0;


while (r != rows) {
string::size_type c = 0;
while(c != cols) {
   if (r == 0 || r == rows -1 || c == 0 || c == cols -1) { // if in bordering column or row
            cout << "*";   //output *
        } else {
            if (r == pad + 1 && c == pad + 1) { //if on row for greeting
                cout << greeting; // write greeting
                c += (greeting.size()-1); // adjust invariant
            } else {
                 cout << " ";
            }
        }
        ++c;
    }
    ++r;
    cout << std::endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/mb9InW

Comment: Thanks man.. I knew it would be a simple problem haha.

By the way, am I setting out my code well enough? Where and how much whitespace do you normally use?

Comment: @JonathonQuick You've got one reduntant pair of `{ }` (for the first `else` clause), but otherwise your code is neat.

Comment: @JonathonQuick Each person had their own way of formatting tbh, As long as it is easy for you (and preferably others) to read the code back and understand it, thats all that matters. The way you write your code is fine =)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from reseting the variable c in the outer loop, you are not getting padding between the asterick and the message. So for that include the below code just after where you are printing the message.

```
for(int i = 0;i<pad;i++)
{
    cout<<" ";
}
```